# Import csv file from vba without giving a table name

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010

I am trying to import a csv file from a directory into access database. I am able to import but whenever I import the name of the file gets changed and I dont want the filename to be changed. I want the table name as the same name as csv file. How do i do this? Here is my code:
strInitialDirectory = "S:\"

```
strPathFile = ahtCommonFileOpenSave(InitialDir:=strInitialDirectory, _
      Filter:=strFilter, OpenFile:=False, _
      DialogTitle:=strBrowseMsg, _
      Flags:=ahtOFN_HIDEREADONLY)

If strPathFile = "" Then
      MsgBox "No file was selected.", vbOK, "No Selection"
      Exit Sub
End If

' Replace tablename with the real name of the table into which
' the data are to be imported
  strTable = strPathFile

DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, strTable, strPathFile, blnHasFieldNames

End Sub
```

If the csv file name is StudentRecords18/19.csv, then the table name should also be StudentRecords18/19. I can set this in strtable but I dont want to since I will importing different data each month hence it will contain the same table name with 1 and so on at the end but different data..

Comment: I'm a bit confused. If the code is always importing the same file name then you mean you want to always create a new table with the same name? Or are you trying to *append* to the same table name?

Comment: So if once i Import a csv file and I define it to strTable= "StudentRecords", then the the imported excel file will be saved as "StudentRecords". However when i import it next time a different csv file, it will also be saved as studentRecords so it will create duplicates table. When I import next time, I could set the strTable to a different name and it will be saved as different name in access. I am just looking for a quicker way if theres any to import excel files and save it as a new tables without changing the excel file name.

Comment: I'm not understanding why you can't set strTable to the same value as the file name (strPathFile?). That also appears to be variable - changes each time? Or are you saying the csv file name is always "StudentRecords"? And what, all of a sudden, does Excel have to do with this? Are you looking for the `InputBox` function where you can type in a name?

Comment: Csv file names are different but the table name in access is always the same.. e.g. if i import once it will be saved as studentrecords, if i import another csv at a different time it will be saved as studentrecords1 and so on...

Comment: Yes, so assign the file name each time to `strTable`.